# Android SimpleCursorAdapter ID from Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, simplecursoradapter

I'm having somewhat of an issue in an application I'm developing.
So, all my tables have _id fields for primary keys, and I use SimpleCursorAdapter to bind them to ListViews and Spinners.
What I wanted to know is how can I make the ListView or Spinner selected item have the same ID as the corresponding row?

The strange thing is that this works with the ContextMenu, which I am using straight of the NotePad example:

```
AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
info.id
```

This ID field **IS** the same as the RowID on the table, and I can delete items fine, but when I try something like this:

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
                int position, long arg) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    FuelingList.class);
            long id = view.getId();
```

The ID field is some random rubberish.
So my question is, in the first code bit, what Id is the *AdapterContextMenuInfo* getting and how can I retrieve it in other parts of my code?

Comment: Sorry I didn't know that. Will do, thanks!

Comment: Also another thing, in any other place of the code (not on listener) if I need to access the ID of the selected item, is there any simpler way than doing `((SimpleCursorAdapter) item.getAdapter())
         .getCursor().getLong(
           ((SimpleCursorAdapter) fuelType
             .getAdapter()).getCursor()
             .getColumnIndex("_id"))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a SimpleCursorAdapter, the onItemClick is passing the database row id in to you..

```
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg)
```

The `long arg` part is actually your row id from the database.

So your code should be:

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, 
            int position, long arg) { 
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
                FuelingList.class); 
        long id = arg;
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you know you are using a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, then in your `onItemClick` method, you can call

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg) {
   String value = ((SimpleCursorAdapter) adapter.getAdapter()).getCursor().getString(COLUMN_INDEX);
}
```

Where `COLUMN_INDEX` in the column that you want to fetch from the currently select row in the cursor.

Alternately, calling

```
adapter.getAdapter().getItem(position)
```

and then casting that to a `Cursor`, works as well.

NOTE 1: The `AdapterView` is actually your `ListView`.

NOTE 2: Since you using a `SimpleCursorAdapter` then `getItem(position)` on the Adapter returns the `Cursor` positioned at the row your specifed

NOTE 3: When you have `Cursor`, you can fetch data by providing the column index (0 based) or by using `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("COLUMN_NAME"))`

NOTE 4: As per Barak's comment the `arg` parameter is the value from the _ID field when using a `CursorAdapter`, if all you need to know is the row `_ID`, then just use the `arg` value.

Comment: I'm getting this error `Cannot cast from AdapterView<capture#1-of ?> to SimpleCursorAdapter`.
Also I'm not saving the ID on any field of the ListView, but the Menu seems to be able to access it...

Comment: perhaps try, ((SimpleCursorAdapter)getListView().getAdapter()).getCursor(), instead.

Comment: None of it works, I get invalid cast errors.
The real question here is, how does AdapterContextMenuInfo get the correct ID?

Comment: Thank you very much anyway because I think this is the correct answer, I just have to find a way to make it work.

Comment: I originally casted the `AdapterView` to an `Adapter` which was incorrect :(  I've fixed the answer to include the correct code.  BTW, if you accepted the answer, could you also "Accpet" it in StackOverflow as ... reputation doesn't build itself :)

Comment: That's like running around the car three times before you get in... the row id from the database is given in the parameters passed in to the method. It's the `long arg` part.

Comment: @Barak The way I understand it, is that @vascoFG wants to get something OTHER than the `_ID` value from the selected item (which is the `arg` parameter).  Hence, using `getItem(position)` (or simply `getCursor()`) to get the `Cursor` allows you to fetch ANY data from the current record.

Comment: Heh, I took this part "This ID field IS the same as the RowID on the table" to mean that was exactly what he was looking for.  Either way, he now has info for each.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you store the ids of rows in an arraylist and take the id of the row from corresponding position of arraylist. This worked for me..

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Intent intent=new Intent(this , Details.class);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putLong("ID", IDList.get(position));
    intent.putExtras(extras);
    startActivityForResult(intent, SHOW_DETAILS);

}
```

You can use listview.setonitenclicklistener... Hope it helps